# my app requires more permissions than needs

Tags: java, android

I have these permissions in my `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="dea.gov.ge.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

But in google play my app requires more permissions:

> Identity
>
> find accounts on the device;
>
> Contacts
>
> find accounts on the device;
>
> Location
>
> approximate location (network-based);
>   precise location (GPS and network-based);
>
> Phone
>
> read phone status and identity;
>
> Photos/Media/Files
>
> modify or delete the contents of your USB storage;
>   read the contents of your USB storage;
>
> Storage
>
> modify or delete the contents of your USB storage;
>   read the contents of your USB storage;
>
> Wi-Fi connection information
>
> view Wi-Fi connections;
>   Device ID & call information;
>   read phone status and identity
>
> Other
>   receive data from Internet;
>   full network access;
>   read Google service configuration;
>   view network connections;
>   use accounts on the device;

I have google maps where i'm inserting some markers from xml file. and getting `IMEI` code.

But why does it needs contacts, photo/media files, storage etc.?

Comment: It's because the map, see this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/2lsAUl9mgUo